# Strange Mouse Problem - Clicks not registered middle top of screen

Tags: 20.04, gnome, mouse

There is a region on my screen, about 25% of the width and 25% of the height, aligned middle top.  It does not register any mouse clicks.  Mouse clicks work fine everywhere else.  The mouse pointer changes to a normal pointer as it transitions from elsewhere into this region.  It feels like there's some kind of overlay here but I tried killing processes one by one and it's still there.

Even weirder, I can drag windows by their top bar using the mouse inside this region, but if I drop it in there, I can't pick it up anymore.

System Info

- 32G Memory
- AMD® Ryzen 5 5600x 6-core processor × 12
- AMD® Radeon rx 6600 xt
- 4.5TB disk
- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64-bit
- Gnome 3.36.8 with X11

  - gnome/focal 1:3.30+2 amd64
  - xserver-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.8 all [installed,automatic]
  - x11-common/focal,focal,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 all [installed,automatic]
- kernel: Linux 5.15.0-83-generic

UPDATE:

FIRST of all, installing xfce4 and logging into an xfce session instead of a gnome one makes this problem go away, so I have a work-around.  But it's still there in gnome.

result of `xprop _NET_WM_PID` and clicking on the window is: `_NET_WM_PID:  not found.`

output of `xwininfo -tree`

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x77 (has no name)

  Root window id: 0x6bf (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x6bf (the root window) (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x200011 "gnome-shell": ()  1920x1080+0+0  +0+0
```

output of `xwininfo -all`

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x77 (has no name)

  Root window id: 0x6bf (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x6bf (the root window) (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x200011 "gnome-shell": ()  1920x1080+0+0  +0+0

  Absolute upper-left X:  0
  Absolute upper-left Y:  0
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1920
  Height: 1080
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x21
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x20 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: ForgetGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: yes
  Corners:  +0+0  -0+0  -0-0  +0-0
  -geometry 1920x1080+0+0

  Bit gravity: ForgetGravity
  Window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Backing-store hint: NotUseful
  Backing-planes to be preserved: 0xffffffff
  Backing pixel: 0
  Save-unders: No

  Someone wants these events:
  Do not propagate these events:
  Override redirection?: Yes

  No window manager hints defined
  Window manager hints:
      Process id: (unknown)

  No normal window size hints defined
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

Comment: Try this: get the PID of the process that owns the invisible window by entering the command `xprop _NET_WM_PID`. The cursor will turn into a cross. With this, click in the middle top region. Return to the terminal. The process ID will be displayed. Then find the process itself: `ps [enter PID here]`.

Comment: Thanks!  But oddly enough, it says `not found`:

`~ $ xprop _NET_WM_PID` .... `_NET_WM_PID:  not found.`

Comment: So, to be clear, that works for clicking on my browser, terminal, etc, and it gives the PID.  But when I click in this region I describe, it always gives `not found`, regardless of what process is on top or if the desktop is on top.

Comment: Weird. Another utility is `xwininfo`. Enter `xwininfo -tree` and click in the spooky area.

Comment: Updated description with that output, seems so weird, going to get my exact X11 and Gnome version, and maybe try different versions.

Comment: ah, interesting, it goes away in xfce4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed xfce4, used that for a bit, the weird region wasn't present there.  I then logged into Wayland because I didn't love that xfce4 kept putting my system to sleep and there seemed to be no way of controlling when and why, and it would freeze on resume.  Wayland also didn't have a problem area.  I then logged back into my default Ubuntu Gnome and the weird region is gone!

There be dragons here I'm sure, but for the time being I have a blindfold on.